# How to read cookie in PortletRequest after being set by HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cookies, http-redirect, ibm-rad

### **Goal:**

1) Save cookie via HttpServletResponse.addCookie()

2) Redirect via HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect() to new instance of portlet.

3) Read cookie in Portlet via PortletRequest

### **Problem:**

Cookie is set and can be seen in FireBug. Cannot read cookie from my PortletRequest object.

---

**Set Cookie and redirect:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/setCookie", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final void setCookie(@RequestParam(value = "cookievalue") String cookieValue, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {

    Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("cookieName", cookieValue);
    myCookie.setPath("/");
    myCookie.setMaxAge(999999);
    myCookie.setSecure(true);
    response.addCookie(myCookie);

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    response.setHeader("HeaderName", "/path/to/redirect");
    response.sendRedirect("/path/to/redirect"); //within same domain
}
```

---

**Read Cookie:**

```
@RequestMapping
public String doView(PortletRequest request, PortletResponse response, Model model) {
    //how do I read my cookie from request?
}
```

Comment: What about `portletRequest.getCookies()`?